# Use a static variable or method for a constant array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, static, constants

I'm wondering if it is better to use a final static variable or method to provide a constant array in Java.

Say we have:

```
public class myColor {
    public final static String[] COLOR_NAMES = new String[] {"red", "green"};
    public final static String[] colorNames() {return new String[] {"red", "green"};}
}
```

To me, the second one has the disadvantage that each time it's called a new String array is created. But the first one has the disadvantage, that anyone could do `COLOR_NAMES[0] = "blue"`.

To clarify: I specifically want to provide a list of color names for a subsequent match with regular expressions.

Is there any established way how this is typically solved?

Comment: This is example for using `Enum`

Comment: _But the first one has the disadvantage, that anyone could do COLOR_NAMES[0] = "blue"._

Why is that a disadvantage? It's a final array isn't it?

Comment: Or use Enum... maybe ?

Comment: @cbach the array is final but not its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can go with a list, one option would be:

```
public final static List<String> COLOR_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableList(
                                                   Arrays.asList("red", "green"));
```

You can always get an array if needed:

```
String[] array = COLOR_NAMES.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Otherwise your second option is fine although I would write it:

```
private final String[] COLOR_NAMES = {"red", "green"};
public static String[] getColorNames() { return COLOR_NAMES.clone(); }
```

Comment: An unmodifiable list is indeed maybe the best solution, thanks. Considering the second option, does it perform better, or is it a style thing? :-)

Comment: @Jay Style. It does exactly the same thing your code did, although if you ever had to add a color you'd only need to change one array instead of two.

Answer (score 3):

You can use enum

```
public enum Color{ 

  RED("red"), GREEN("green");
   final String color;

  Color(String color) {
    this.color=color;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }
 }
```

Comment: you can make `color` final and private.

Comment: How can I get a list / array of all the defined enum names?

Comment: `Color.values()` will return a `Color[]` of all the enums

Comment: Ok, but I would have to convert those to a String array --> not really better than using a method in the first place.

Although I admit that enums are more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This question is fall for using `Enum`. Personally I wont be using any method for that. But weather static array is good solution for that? It is better to solve it using [java enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

To initialise an array at construction time you can specify a list values in curly braces:

```
private static final String[] STRING_ARRAY = {"red", "green", "blue"};
```

In my example I have assumed that you won't want to change the instance of array and so have declared it final. You still would be able to update individual entries like so:

```
 array[0] = "1";
```

But you won't be able to replace the array with a different one completely. If the values are going to change a lot - especially if the **number of values are going to change** - then it may be worth considering using **List** instead.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP shows that he already knows how to initialize an array at constant time, and he's interested providing a **constant** array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `new String[]` is not necessary for static initialization. Didn't know that, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: @Jay I believe what Sanjay wrote is simply syntactic sugar; the `new String[]` is still there, but "hidden"